# What is the equation of the expectation of the product of two normally distributed multivariate random variables?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Given two multivariate random variables $\mathbf{x} \sim N(\hat{\mathbf{x}}, Q)$, $\mathbf{y}\sim N(\hat{\mathbf{y}}, R)$ which are not independent but are correlated with covariance matrix $C$ and a constant matrix $A$. What is the expectation of $\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{y}$, i.e. $E[\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{y}]$? What if $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are independent? Note that I'm using $\mathbf{x}^T$ to mean the transpose of $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: I am putting no constraints on the joint distribution. Would it simplify matters to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited in response to OP's edits of the question**

$C$ is $n\times n$ covariance matrix of 
(column) $n$-vectors $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$. The $i$-$j$-th 
entry in $C$ is $c_{i,j} = \text{cov}(X_i, Y_j)$.  Now,
$E[X_i]=\hat{x}_i$ and $E[Y_j]=\hat{y}_j$ so that 
$c_{i,j} = E[X_iY_j]-\hat{x}_i\hat{y}_j$.  Then,
$$\begin{align*}
E[\mathbf x^TA\mathbf y] &= E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j}X_iY_j\right]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j}E[X_iY_j]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j}(c_{i,j}+\hat{x}_i\hat{y}_j)\\
&= \hat{\bf x}\,^TA\hat{\bf y} + \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j}c_{i,j}.
\end{align*}$$
If $C = \mathbf 0$ is the all-zeroes matrix,
then we get 
$$E[\mathbf x^TA\mathbf y] 
= \hat{\mathbf x}\,^TA\hat{\mathbf y} = E[\mathbf{x}]^TAE[\bf y]$$
as in Robert Israel's answer. (However, Robert has not as yet
revised his answer
in response to your edits that make the $X_i$ and $Y_j$ non-zero-mean
random variables and so $E[\mathbf{x}]^TAE[\mathbf y]$ does not equal
$0$ when $C = \mathbf 0$ as he says). Note that normality of $\mathbf x$ and/or $\mathbf y$ has nothing to do 
with the matter.

Comment: What about the case when $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are correlated?

Comment: $C$ _is_ the matrix from which you can read off the covariance of _any_ component $X_i$ of $\mathbf x$ and _any_ component $Y_j$ of $\mathbf y$. The correlation matrices $Q$ and $R$ specify only the covariances of $X_i$ and $X_j$ and $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ respectively, and are not relevant to the computation of $E[\mathbf x^TA\mathbf y]$ which depends on $C$ and not at all on what $Q$ and $R$ are.

Comment: +1. The last double sum is the trace of the matrix $AC^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Unless $\bf x$ and $\bf y$ are uncorrelated, you haven't given us enough information.  If they are uncorrelated, $E[{\bf x}^T A {\bf y}] = E[{\bf x}]^T A E[{\bf y}] = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I updated my question to clarify.